# Port forwarding through multiple routers?

Tags: networking, home-networking

I want to use a Linksys wireless-g router as an extender/network switch. I've heard that if I leave the router in router mode and have it connected to the main router (my RT-AC86U router) it will act as a switch/network switch. I've already done that. Now I need to port forward to the devices on the Linksys, but since the devices now work on an entirely different intranet I was wondering if it's still possible to port forward to devices on the secondary router.

Comment: Question really needs a bit of clarification. If your device is meant to work _purely_ as a switch, then where does the "entirely different intranet" come from? And if there are really two separate networks, then the Linksys device is acting as a full router and _not_ as an "extender". (It still also has a switch function but that's no longer relevant.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two routers with NAT in series, how to forward a port?](https://superuser.com/questions/1107632/two-routers-with-nat-in-series-how-to-forward-a-port)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should consider whether you want the Linksys to work as a router or as a switch. Using it as a switch is the easiest way, all connected devices are in the same network, you configure a port forwarding in the main router and you are done.

If you use the Linksys as a NAT router, it is a little more complicated. The external connection to the Linksys is provided by the main router, the internal devices behind the Linksys need a network range different from the range of the main router. You have to configure a port forwarding from the main router to the external address of the Linksys and another port forwarding from the Linksys to the target device.

Comment: Thanks, this answered my question. I wanted to sandbox for the most part my other devices on the Linksys, so I will keep both in NAT mode and port forward from the main router to the Linksys, then to the device(s).